# Phrase or One word for those who actually work for an achievment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose, there is a project which has been successfully completed by a group of people (including seniors, juniors and labour class). we want to appreciate not only the people at management level, but also those who actually worked hard and implemented the tasks allocated by the management team to achieve those results.
what is the one word / phrase for such people, who implemented those tasks.

Comment: Are you saying that the top level managers didn't actually work towards that achievement?

Comment: _Goal-oriented, determined, focused_ etc. Look for synonyms.

Comment: hi NVZ, thanks for above. Here the issue is not that who worked and who did not work. its about the appreciation which is normally given only to the top level managers. And the the real implementers are forgotten. i'm not sure whether the term "implementers" is correct for them or not?

Comment: Check if _implementer_ sounds right for your purpose. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/implementer

Comment: Also see: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/implementer-role.html

Comment: thanks for above. the term 'implementer' might be ok, but it does not seem to fit the actual context in which we need such word/phrase.

Comment: It is late in my time zone, and all I can think of is "worker bees" which you absolutely should NOT use.

Comment: I would call them, simply "the people who did the work".

Comment: laborers would be my take ... although it might seem a bit tongue in cheek

Comment: I don't know how common my own use of words is, but I like "management" Vs "operational". Depending on the nature of the work "technician" may be a useful word.

Answer (score 2):

> **In the trenches**
> adverb phrase
>
> In the workplace; in contact with the people or problems in a situation; unprotected by distance or illusion.

"We want to appreciate not only the people at management level, but also those who are *in the trenches*, getting the job done.